# Creating a custom requirement validator for @Route annotation in Symfony

Tags: symfony

As you can see below, my `@Route->requirements` regex below (I'm using it in many other controller/methods) is a bit long, doesn't look good and **most importantly** *it could be hard to maintain in the case of syntax update* in future so the question is, are we able to do something like below?

I've seen many similar questions and tutorials for creating custom annotations but not something like this question.

**CURRENT**

```
/**
 * @param string $id
 *
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Route("/class/{id}", requirements={"id"="([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}"})
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getClassAction($id)
```

**MAYBE SOMETHING LIKE THIS**

```
/**
 * @param string $id
 *
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Route("/class/{id}", requirements={"id"="MyClass::MyValidation"})
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getClassAction($id)
```

**MyClass**

```
MyClass
{
     // Would be ideal to stick this into parameters.yml though
     const ID = "([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}";

     public function MyValidation($value)
     {
          if (!preg_match(self::ID, $value)) {
               return 'Bad ID';
          }

          return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the pattern directly as follow :

```
<?php

use X\Y\Z\MyClass;

class XYZ
{

/**
 * @param string $id
 *
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Route("/class/{id}", requirements={"id":MyClass::ID})
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getClassAction($id)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me. Would you please shown an example? Thanks

Comment: Ok i just read your code carefully everything is OK just remove "" quotes around static call as following `"id"=MyClass::MyValidation`  and place `use Namespace\MyClass` at the namespace use section

Comment: I've just made my possible solution up to explain what exactly I meant by my question so if had to implement what you've just suggested, I would get an`AnnotationException` error.

Comment: I'm on mobile when I get back the home I'll check ~ 30 min

Comment: I updated my answer could you please check and provide your symfony version ?

Comment: Btw, could you please remove method and secure annotations and try again ? there may be a problem I'm not sure, because I use security annotation as like that     ` * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")` not `@Secure`

Comment: Oopps Btw, @BentCoder just put the constant there not the function route annotation already preg matches, you don't need to implement preg match just send ID as "id": MyClass::ID everything would be fine if your pattern is OK, it looks OK.

Comment: Thanks @FZE I'll check it tomorrow. I'm on v2.8.2

Comment: OK, I've just quickly tested and `requirements={"id"=GuidAnnotation::ID}` works fine without having any method in the class. Thanks. Plus 1

Comment: Sorry, I did missed that you are using callback in there if I aware earlier it would be solved without struggling :) Your welcome btw.

Comment: That's fine. Have you tried getting the value from `config.yml` or `parameters.yml` instead of creating a class just for a constant? It would be much better or something similar. I mean this: e.g. `requirements={"id":parameters.yml:ID})`

Comment: I'm not sure but according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382355/configurable-parameters-in-symfony2-entity-annotation question it is not possible, so why do you need that ? then just put your route rules to routing.yml ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `@ParamConverter` annotation instead. In this case you won't need to validate. For more info [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}")
 * @ParamConverter("post", class="SensioBlogBundle:Post")
 */
public function showAction(Post $post)
{
}
```