# got trouble when using SensioFrameworkExtraBundle @Security & @IsGranted in Symfony 2.8

Tags: routes, symfony-2.8

so i want implement feature which can check if specific roles can access the route(url) or not using  SensioFrameworkExtraBundle @Security&@IsGranted from here https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html

and im using symfony 2.8

the problem its when i add IsGranted in my controller i got this error message

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted" in method AppBundle\Controller\ProductController::newAction() does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded in /home/lavin/mini-project/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/home/lavin/mini-project/app/config/routing.yml").

so i tried search some open case in stack overflow but some answer in other thread still make me confuse to solve this issue like this thread
[Creating a custom requirement validator for @Route annotation in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042152/creating-a-custom-requirement-validator-for-route-annotation-in-symfony)

and this one
[symfony2: check isGranted for a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015763/symfony2-check-isgranted-for-a-route)

and this is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use AppBundle\Entity\Cart;
use AppBundle\Entity\CartProduct;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home")
     */
    public function homeAction()
    {
        return $this->render('product/home.html.twig');
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("product/new", name="product_new")
     * 
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_SELLER")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
```

so i expected the router url "/product/new" just can be accessed by user who has ROLE_SELLER and user with ROLE_CUSTOMER cant open or accessed that