# Best way to define constraints with parameters

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-validator

I tried to use parameters in annotations, but [it didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382355/configurable-parameters-in-symfony2-entity-annotation)

e.g. in object constraints:

```
...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SomeObj {

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="%max_filesize%")
     */
    private $file;

    ...

}
```

in parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    ...
    max_filesize: 5M
```

I got `ConstraintDefinitionException('"%max_filesize%" is not a valid maximum size')`.

I believe I have to drop using annotation format and try some other (YAML?). Or extend FileConstraint with new class and somehow set $maxFilesize there from parameters. What'are the other solutions to this problem and which one is the best?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configurable parameters in Symfony2 entity annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382355/configurable-parameters-in-symfony2-entity-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{ size }}` instead of `%max_filesize%`.

See the [doc reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsizemessage).

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? Where should I use %value% instead of %max_filesize% and how will it help me?